# What is the convergence of the series of $u_n=\frac{1}{(n-1)^\alpha}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^\alpha}-\frac{2}{n^\alpha}$ when $\alpha$ isn't $1$ or $0$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence

let be 
$u_n=\frac{1}{(n-1)^\alpha}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^\alpha}-\frac{2}{n^\alpha}$.

Examine the convergence of these series.

I distinguished three cases the first $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha=-1$ are obvious (simple convergence towards 0 and divergence). but what about the third one? I'm thinking about Taylor expansion but I don't know which one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)^\alpha}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^\alpha}-\frac{2}{n^\alpha}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)^\alpha}-\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\right)-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^\alpha}\right)\\
&=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^\alpha}-\frac12+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^\alpha}
\end{align}
converges if $\alpha\ge0$.